# How to make the arrow fix to a div card?

Tags: html, css

I have a list of cards arranged in a row. I can scroll right or left to see more cards.

I can select a card and it expands. When it expands there will be a small panel which pops down with an arrow pointing to it.

When I scroll right or left I want the arrow to **move along the panels width**. How do I achieve that using CSS only ?

[Here is the image of the UI i want to build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgJgj.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to ask a question you must provide a **[Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)** **in the question itself** preferably in the form of a stack snippet.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.arrow_box {
 position: relative;
 background: #CCC;
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 50vh;
}
.arrow_box:after {
 bottom: 100%;
 left: 50%;
 border: solid transparent;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
 border-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0);
 border-bottom-color: #CCC;
 border-width: 30px;
 margin-left: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow_box">
  arrow_box
</div>
```